# QGIS: separately adjust a polygon layer's fill and boundary opacity?

Tags: qgis, symbology, transparency-opacity

At 3.10.3, adjusting a polygon layer's opacity affects both the fill and the outer boundary stroke simultaneously, as shown in this screenshot:

[image]

I want to *separately* adjust the fill and boundary opacity.  The only way I've been able to accomplish this is to draw the layer twice, once for the fill and once for the boundary.

Is it possible to separately adjust the fill and boundary within a *single* layer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you select `Simple Fill` instead of `Fill` in the dialog, you will be able to change fill (*Fill color*) and stroke (*Stroke color*) independently:

[image]

To set the opacity, click on the small down-arrow to the right of the `Fill color` / `Stroke color` area and use the slider below the colour circle to adjust the transparency / opacity.
See the screenshot below, where the cursor is on the slider.

[image]

Comment: Adjusting the opacity is done with a slider  below the color circle when you open the fill color or stroke color selection.

Comment: @user30184 Perfect, that's it!  My eyes were looking for a slider bar like the one shown in my OP, and they missed the different style that you pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

When you click on `Simple fill` you're able to set the **fill color** opacity and **stroke color** opacity separately ... doesn't it fit your needs ?